# How to write a common function or file for replaceable placeholder text in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a project for email content editor with some default placeholders which will be replaceable with the user data stored in database. I have created & completed the content editor part, after that I don't get any proper clue to start a common function or file which will replace the placeholder's text with the dynamic relation model values and this function or file need to be reusable with entire project.

For better understanding, I'm having a content with placeholders like,

```
"Hello {customer_name}, This is your content of the day {content_date}"
```

Which should be replaced with the database values dynamically,

```
"Hello Mano, This is your content of the day 3-Feb-2023"
```

Please note, I'm using One to Many relation model to get the content data. I need to use the same structural to be followed.

Sample code 1:

```
$contents = EmailContent::all();
foreach($contents as $inv)
{
    $message = $inv->email_content;
    $message = str_replace('{customer_name}' , $inv->customer->name, $message);
    $message = str_replace('{content_date}', $inv->content_date, $message);
}
```

The above sample code is working fine, but I need to be maintain the replaceable placeholders in a common file or function for other placeholders too.

Sample code 2:

```
$contents = EmailContent::all();
foreach($contents as $inv)
{
    $userData = User::find($inv->user_id);
    $message = $inv->email_content;
    $message = str_replace('{user_fullname}', $userData->fullname, $emailBody);
    $message = str_replace('{user_company_name}' , $userData->company_name, $emailBody);
}
```

So, what I want to achieve here is the placeholders are need to group together and maintain in a common place. Those records going to used for future add or update.

In the result of the file or function,

```
$message = str_replace('{customer_name}' , $inv->customer->name, $message);
$message = str_replace('{content_date}', $inv->content_date, $message);
$message = str_replace('{user_fullname}', $userData->fullname, $emailBody);
$message = str_replace('{user_company_name}' , $userData->company_name, $emailBody);
// return $message;
// or 
// echo $message;
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged `laravel`, what is keeping you from using the [built-in translations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings) for this? All of the strings will be kept in a central translations file and even help you support multiple languages if you need it in the future.

Comment: @D1__1 Actually I'm a beginner in `laravel`. And In my case, the placeholder texts are not pre-set with fixed string or values. It's values are going to be dynamically replaceable from the relationship model data values. After that, I'm going to send the  complete user understandable paragraph to customers in email.